# Following a GitHub Article on Testing My SSH Connection But I Receive This Message zsh: command not found: $

Tags: macos, github, terminal

So i'm following the github article to test my SSH connection by copy pasting the command found in this article in my terminal but it gives me this message:

zsh: command not found: $

Also im on MacOS if that helps

article:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the `$` in your copy-paste.

The $ is commonly used to indicate that the following code will be a terminal command. But $ is not part of the command itself.